# Updated HTML from JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to build a form with a few number type inputs that the users picks and one checkbox.
im not using php its all java cause im trying to count a bill using his inputs and print out the result.
how do i print those variables? document.write wont do cause its immidetly prints the var without the calculation.

here is some of the script (which is nothing):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.content_window').css('height','900');
    $('#top').css('float','none');
    var shutter_price
    shutter_price = ($('#shutter').val())*200;  
    if (shutter != '0' )
        write(shutter_price);   
});
```

and the form's input:

```
<label for="shutter">shutter </label> 
<input style="margin-right:98px" name="shutter" type="number" id="shutter">
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Java != JavaScript.. also, *don't* use `document.write` after the DOM has been processed/created (it writes *literal HTML* into the open document stream, which is *closed* by the time `ready` is invoked). Instead manipulate the corresponding DOM.

Comment: either add a new field to the page and insert the value there or create a new element and append it to the page. if you don't need to print to screen just use `console.log(shutter_price)` and you can see it in the console (f12).

Comment: (Also, while I said *don't* use `document.write` above, your code is using an unqualified `write` identifier which results in a ReferenceError as there is no standard `window.write` variable; make sure to *read* the error console.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `document.write` it would be better to update or add an element on the page.

For example, modifying your provided code and markup:

### Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.content_window').css('height','900');
    $('#top').css('float','none');

    $('#shutter').on("change", function(e) {
        var shutter_price = $(this).val()*200;
        if (shutter_price >= 0) {
            $('#shutter-result').text(shutter_price);
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<label for="shutter">shutter </label>
<input style="margin-right:98px" name="shutter" type="number" id="shutter" min="0" step="1" pattern="\d+" />

<div id="shutter-result"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/bwa4Q/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a div on your HTML,
and use: `$('#id_of_div_where_you_want_to_write').html("text you want to write");`

p.s. This is javascript
javascript != java o/

Hope it helps bro!

Answer (score 0):

i've typed the whole calculation.
i have a submmision button which by clicking needs to retrive the sum.
it doesnt work... im pretty new at javascript so i cant really tell where is the problem.
here is the code:

```
$('#home_price').submit(function(){
var shutter_price, lights_price, socket_price, screen10_price, screen7_price, dimmer_price, x
var total_price = 3000;
    shutter_price = ($('#shutter').val())*200;
    light_price = ($('#lights').val())*200;
    socket_price = ($('#socket').val())*200;
    screen10_price = ($('#screen10').val())*700;
screen7_price = ($('#screen7').val())*200;
dimmer_price = ($('#dimmer').val())*400;
if($('#boiler').is(":checked")==true){
    total_price+=600;
    x+=1;
}
x+=($('#shutter').val())*2+($('#lights').val())+($('#socket').val());
Math.floor(x);
x+=1;
total_price = total_price + shutter_price + light_price + socket_price + screen10_price + screen7_price +           dimmer_price + x*400;
$('#home_pricing').val()=total_price;
if($('#home_pricing').val() < 6000)
    alert('the solution invalid');
else
    alert(" total: " + $('#home_pricing').val());
});
});
```

and a piece of the html code:

```
<label for="screen7"> 7inch screen </label> 
<input style="margin-right:70px" name="screen7" type="number" id="screen7"> <br><br> 
    <label for="dimmer"> dimmer</label> 
    <input style="margin-right:174px" name="dimmer" type="number" id="dimmer"> <br><br> 
    <label for="boiler"> bolier </label>
    <input style="margin-right:148px" type="checkbox" name="boiler" id="boiler" > <br><br> 
    <div>
    <input type="submit" name=" home_pricing " id="home_pricing" value=" calculate " >
    </div>
    </form>
```

any suggestion of how to make the computation and retrive an alert window or other sort of window with the answer?

tnx

Answer (score -1):

I know you did not say that you are using jquery, but I would highly recommenced it, because it makes javascript a lot easier. If you need to display this value to the user then you can use jquery's html function. Here is the link, https://api.jquery.com/html/. I would just write the value to a div that's is suppose to display the answer.

Let me know if you need it, and I can give you a quick plunker.

Comment: Didn't vote down, but what makes you think the user isn't using jquery?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(e) {` - looks like jQuery to me! :)